# script in php cli stops working silently when I set memory_limit to 128M

Tags: php

I have a script that processes files imporing it db in php cli. 
It works when in php cli `memory_limit` is set to -1, but when I set it to 128M, it stops working silently trying to read file.

`php -i | grep memory_limit` shows now:

```
memory_limit => 128M => 128M
suhosin.memory_limit => 0 => 0
```

How understand what causes an issue? Why php script stops silently and there is not message about exausting memory limit?

Answer (score 0):

You should have an error; if you don't have it it's because you don't display errors.

If your using Debian, be careful, CLI & Apache's PHP don't use the same php.ini file (that may be the reason why you don't see errors in CLI).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Why error message about memory is not displayed? Why does it work without memory limit and stops working with memory_limit set to 128M, trying to read file? I used Debian, I know it has seperate php.ini, and judging from php -i | grep memory_limit, I set memory_limit correctly.

Comment: If you do the same grep for error_reporting & display_errors, what does it output?
Anyway, your problem is linked to this memory_limit, you'll need optimizations if you must not use more than 128M.

Comment: php -i | grep display_errors shows: display_errors => STDOUT => STDOUT
suhosin.disable.display_errors => Off => Off

Comment: Well, I don't know Suhosin very well, but did you try to force suhosin.disable.display_errors to On?

Comment: But judging from suhosin.disable.display_errors name it should be off, as it is.

Comment: It looks like I don't get any error messages no matter if suhosin.disable.display_errors is on or off.